# Form validation, php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I have a form, as such

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" id="search">
    <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

I want to make sure the data is valid, so I have a php file I can make an ajax request to access a database, which returns xml as such

```
<id="111111" first_name="Tom" last_name="Hanks" />
```

If there is a matching name. There should be no name conflicts. "HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found" is printed otherwise.  After this is done, I want to reach search.php with first_name, last_name, and id. That is, I want to be at:

```
search.php?first_name=Tom&last_name=Hanks&id=111111
```

How would I go about this ?

Comment: What have you tried?  What part of your code doesn't work?  And what in the name of Jesse James does it have to do with "prototype"?

Comment: Out of the 7 questions you have asked so far on Stack-Overflow, you still have 0% acceptance rating. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for a couple of hints on how this community works.  The answers given to you by the community deserve some feedback on your part.  Good-day friend.

Comment: Your question is incredibly broad and contains some information that doesn't make sense (why would PHP be making an AJAX call at all, much less to a DB which it can presumably link against directly?)  I suspect a better question to ask would be for PHP, HTML, XML, and AJAX tutorials, until you understand what the technologies are and how they're used a little better  -- at least well enough to explain your question better.

Comment: just a simple javascript function is needed that checks if `first_name` `last_name` is set and then continues to search.php if true, no need too use ajax or any fancy jquery, note you should really use POST as the method, i guess the question your asking is you need the id first as thats what your matching to your sql query. your methodology is out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your scenario is similar to the followings, which im sure, you can churn to your own flavors.
[1] http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax-validate/
[2] http://www.dev102.com/2008/05/21/create-interactive-form-validation-using-ajax/